# for loop and apply to calculate means

Tags: r, list, for-loop, apply

i want to calculate the means for 32 vectors in a list. I thought this code should do the job:

```
for(i in sequence(length(means16list))){
  mat.means16 <- apply(means16list, 1, mean)
}
```

where `means16list` contains 32 numeric vectors and `mat.means16` should contain the means. It is a matrix 4,4 and defined in a previous step.
Maybe I did not understand how loops work yet.
Can someone help?

Cheers

Comment: So `means16list` is a list with 32 elements, each element being a numeric vector? In which case `sapply(means16list, mean)` should do it.

Comment: I have an inkling it might be a matrix given the output dimensions.

Comment: Good rule of thumb: if you use `i` in the definition of a loop, you need to use `i` inside the loop too. Otherwise you're just running the exact same line of code again and again.

Answer (score 2):

`mat.means16` is being overridden each time, you should make a list and store the results there potentially.

---

There are likely better ways to do this if you post example data, I'm assuming you want `rowMeans()` of a matrix.

```
results <- lapply(means16list, rowMeans)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood, why not just:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
means16list <- lapply(1:32, function(x) runif(10))

# Return a list of the sample means
lapply(means16list, mean);

# Return a vector of the sample means
sapply(means16list, mean);
```

I don't see the point of the `for` loop. `lapply`/`sapply` will loop through every element of your list and apply function `mean` to it.